# Magento - get cart items for a given product id

Tags: magento

I try to get the cart items for a given product;

I have tried this code :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load('2784');

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    echo $item->getId()."<br/>";
}
```

but it don't gives anything.

How can I modify my code to use "getItemByProduct" in the right form ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10):

[`getItemByProduct()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.html#getItemByProduct) returns the first matching `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` so there is no need for an extra loop.

```
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
if ($item !== false) echo $item->getId();
```

Comment: I get an error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /catalog/product/list.phtml on line 996

Comment: If `$product` is not in `$quote` then `$item` will be `false`. That is one thing which might cause the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
foreach ($quote->getItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getProductId() == $product->getId()) {
        print_r($item->getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: And how can I directly use getItemByProduct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `getItemByProduct()` function on the `checkout/cart` or `checkout/quote` model as that method is of the `sales/quote` model.

You can find this method at the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote class`. so it is used withe `sales/quote`. hope this  is useful.